# Управление keyframes через JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation

У меня есть анимация, прописанная в CSS:

```css
@keyframes slideIn {
  from { width: 0px; }
  to { width: 40px; }
}
```

После того, как я увожу курсор с элемента, должна производиться другая анимация:

```css
@keyframes slideOut {
  from { width: 40px; }  
  to { width: 0px; }
}
```

Но, я не понимаю, как её присвоить элементу. Точнее, запустить анимацию на этом элементе. Вот код JS:

```js
let navBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".nav_link");

for (let i = 0; i < navBtn.length; i++) {
  console.log(navBtn[i]);
  navBtn[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    let ellement = navBtn[i];
    console.log("Элемент с нуммерацией: " + i + " , а так же элементом: " + ellement);
    ellement.classList.add('active');
        
    ellement.addEventListener('pointerout', (b) => {
      if (ellement.classList.contains("active")) {
                console.log("Да, он актив, и ты вышел из объекта");
      }
      setTimeout((b) => {
            
      }, 1600);
    });

  });  
}
```

Вот CSS того элемента, на который будет распространяться анимация:

```css
.nav_link {
  position: relative;
}

.nav_link:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;

  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  animation-duration: .8s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
}
```

Добавил класс, всё хорошо работает, но теперь нужно как-то разобраться с удалением класса `active`, так как даже, если я ставлю `setTimeout`, то все равно класс сразу удаляется после увода, поэтому хотел бы услышать исправление!
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Знаю что можно через добавления классов, но не хочу делать все циклами, хотелось бы вариант попроще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let navBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".nav_link");

for (let i = 0; i < navBtn.length; i++) {
console.log(navBtn[i]);
navBtn[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
  let ellement = navBtn[i];
  console.log("Элемент с нуммерацией: " + i + " , а так же элементом: " + ellement);
  ellement.classList.add('active');
      
  ellement.addEventListener('pointerout', () => {
    if (ellement.classList.contains("active")) {
        console.log("Да, он актив, и ты вышел из объекта");
    }
    function deleteClasses() {
        if (ellement.classList.contains("active")){
            ellement.classList.remove("active");
        }
    }
    setTimeout(deleteClasses, 750);
  });

});
```

}